# Take out the elements of the most frequently occurring row of a matrix in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix

**In Base R,** is it possible to ***take out (that is, just return the values)*** the elements of the most frequently occurring row in the following matrix?

**Update:** @d.b see your solution seems to pick the wrong pair from matrix `CI.test` below. `CI` has the pick from your solution and `CI.test` is the matrix to pick the elements of the most frequently row from:

```
N = 60 ; df = N-1 ; d = 3

f <- function (ncp, alpha, q, df) {
  abs(suppressWarnings(pt(q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) - alpha)
  }

  a = mapply(c, as.list(20:30), as.list(-20:-30), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) # a list of paired values

 CI.test <- matrix(NA, length(a), 2)

 for(i in 1:length(a)){

CI.test[i,] = sapply(c(0.025, 0.975),
 function(x) optimize(f, interval = a[[i]], alpha = x, q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, tol = 1e-10)[[1]])

   }  

CI = CI.test[which.max(ave(1:nrow(CI.test), do.call(paste, data.frame(CI.test)), FUN = seq_along)), ]


  list(CI, CI.test)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ave` to count the occurrences of the pairs and extract the one that appears the most times

```
m = matrix(c(-5.904236,  7.547438, 3.386315,  7.547438, -7.420706,
                                  7.547438, 3.386315,  7.547438), 4, 2)
m[which.max(ave(1:NROW(m), do.call(paste, data.frame(m)), FUN = seq_along)),]
#[1] 7.547438 7.547438
```

You may need to round values

```
CI.test[which.max(ave(1:NROW(CI.test), do.call(paste, round(data.frame(CI.test), 3)),
                                                                        FUN = seq_along)),]
#[1] 18.59838 27.83543
```

Comment: @rnorouzian, without `round`, the actual values may not be exactly equal.

Comment: I  see but I'm not sure exactly how everything is working here, when you get a chance please let me know how this works, and for example why `paste` is needed.